# How to discover financial Year based on current datetime + asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Financial year start from first of april until next year end of march. So I need to insert data only it become to new financial year otherwise just update the data.
Here is my source code:

```
 Dim nowYear As Integer
    nowYear = Date.Now.Year
    Dim nowMonth As Integer
    nowMonth = Date.Now.Month
    Dim NEWYEAR As Integer
    Dim reccount As Integer = 0
    If nowMonth >= 4 Then
        NEWYEAR = nowYear + 1
    End If


    cmd = New SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ScanningData WHERE ASSET_NUMBER=" & AssetTxt.Text & " AND LOC_DEPT=" & DeptCodeTxt.Text & " and UPDATE_DATE='" & NEWYEAR & "';"
  cmd.Connection = Conn
    rdmysql = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If rdmysql.Read = True Then
        reccount = Val(rdmysql.GetInt32(0))
    End If
    cmd.Dispose()
    rdmysql.Close()

    If reccount = 0 Then
        strsql = "INSERT INTO ScanningData"
        strsql += "(ASSET_NUMBER,LOC_DEPT,DEPT_DESCRIPTION,MAJOR_CATEGORY,DATE_PLACED_IN_SERVICE,LOC_AREA,TAG_NUMBER,CURRENT_UNITS,DESCRIPTION,MYR_COST_BY_UNIT,COST_BY_UNIT,DEPRN_RESERVE_BY_UNIT,DATE_RETIRED,UPDATE_DATE,UPDATE_BY) VALUES "
        strsql += "(@ID, @CODE, @DEPT, @CATEGORY, @SERVICEDATE, @AREA, @TAG, @UNIT, @DESCRIPTION, @MYRCOST, @USDCOST, @DEPR, @RETIREDDATE, @UPDATEDATE, @NAME);"
        cmd = New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = Conn

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", AssetTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", DeptCodeTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEPT", DeptTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORY", CategoryTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERVICEDATE", ServiceTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AREA", LocTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TAG", TagTxt.Text)
        Dim unit As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(UnitTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNIT", unit)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESCRIPTION", DescTxt.Text)
        Dim MYRCost As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(CostMYRTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MYRCOST", MYRCost)
        Dim USDCost As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(CostUSDTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USDCOST", USDCost)
       Dim Depr As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(DeprTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEPR", Depr)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RETIREDDATE", RetiredDateTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UPDATEDATE", ServerDate)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", UserIDLabel.Text)
        cmd.CommandText = strsql
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End If
```

currently my code always insert although it is in the same financial year. It should be update only if with the same financial year

Comment: Is ASSET_NUMBER the primary Key? An identity field (auto-number)?

Comment: @Mary ASSET_NUMBER + LOC_DEPT is the primary key

Comment: Maybe `If nowMonth <= 4 Then nowYear - 1`

Comment: `Val` is redundant here: `Val(rdmysql.GetInt32(0))`. `reccount = rdmysql.GetInt32(0)` will be enough, because `reccount` is `Integer` and `GetInt32(0)` returns `Integer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point of all the date stuff. If a record exists with the composite primary key then it must be updated. If it doesn't exist then it must be inserted. This is true reguardless of the date.

```
Private Sub UpateOrInsertAssets()
        Dim strsql As String
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ScanningData WHERE ASSET_NUMBER= @Asset AND LOC_DEPT= @Dept;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Asset", AssetTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dept", DeptCodeTxt.Text)
        cn.Open()
        Dim reccount As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        cn.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", AssetTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", DeptCodeTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEPT", DeptTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORY", CategoryTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERVICEDATE", ServiceTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AREA", LocTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TAG", TagTxt.Text)
        Dim unit As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(UnitTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNIT", unit)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESCRIPTION", DescTxt.Text)
        Dim MYRCost As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(CostMYRTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MYRCOST", MYRCost)
        Dim USDCost As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(CostUSDTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USDCOST", USDCost)
        Dim Depr As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(DeprTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEPR", Depr)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RETIREDDATE", RetiredDateTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UPDATEDATE", ServerDate)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", UserIDLabel.Text)
        If reccount = 0 Then 'The record doesn't exist
            strsql = "INSERT INTO ScanningData"
            strsql += "(ASSET_NUMBER,LOC_DEPT,DEPT_DESCRIPTION,MAJOR_CATEGORY,DATE_PLACED_IN_SERVICE,LOC_AREA,TAG_NUMBER,CURRENT_UNITS,DESCRIPTION,MYR_COST_BY_UNIT,COST_BY_UNIT,DEPRN_RESERVE_BY_UNIT,DATE_RETIRED,UPDATE_DATE,UPDATE_BY) VALUES "
            strsql += "(@ID, @CODE, @DEPT, @CATEGORY, @SERVICEDATE, @AREA, @TAG, @UNIT, @DESCRIPTION, @MYRCOST, @USDCOST, @DEPR, @RETIREDDATE, @UPDATEDATE, @NAME);"
            cmd.CommandText = strsql
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()
        ElseIf reccount = 1 Then 'The record exists
            cmd.CommandText = "Update ScanningData Set ASSET_NUMBER = @ID,LOC_DEPT = @CODE,DEPT_DESCRIPTION = @DEPT,
            MAJOR_CATEGORY = @CATEGORY,DATE_PLACED_IN_SERVICE = @SERVICEDATE,LOC_AREA = @AREA,TAG_NUMBER = @TAG,
            CURRENT_UNITS = @UNIT,DESCRIPTION = @DESCRIPTION,MYR_COST_BY_UNIT = @MYRCOST, COST_BY_UNIT = @USDCOST,
            DEPRN_RESERVE_BY_UNIT = @DEPR, DATE_RETIRED = @RETIREDDATE, UPDATE_DATE = @UPDATEDATE,UPDATE_BY = @NAME;"
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()
        End If
End Sub
```

You will need to add the appropriate Using statements and/or Try Catch Finally to ensure objects are closed and disposed even in the event of an error.

Comment: date is needed. because i just want to save the data one time only per financial year.